# How to Get-childitem for multiple files only dated today

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to modify a PS script so that it can:

A: Check that multiple files exist and are dated today

B: Do this from multiple locations

```
    $folder = '\\path\subfolder\'
$files = @(
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.txt",
    "file3.txt",
)
Write-Host "Folder: $folder."
# Get only files and only their names
$folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File -Name
foreach ($f in $files) {
    if ($folderFiles -contains $f) { 
        Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green
    } else { 
        Write-Host "File $f was not found!" -foregroundcolor red 
    }
}
```

A the moment this script is designed to only look in one folder and not check for files only dated today. I have no clue how to change it to use multiple folder locations.

Comment: How do you want to store/obtain the file names that you need to check for each folder?

Comment: Do you have a list of folders? You could put them in an array and search through all of those recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is something like this:

```
# create an aray of paths to search through
$folders = '\\server1\share\path\subfolder\', '\\server2\share\path\subfolder\'
# create an array of file names to look for
$files   = 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'
# get the current date as of midnight
$refDate = (Get-Date).Date

# retrieve objects from recursing through the array of folders
Get-ChildItem -Path $folders -Include $files -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refDate } |
    # output whatever properties you want from the files
    Select-Object DirectoryName, Name, LastWriteTime
```

<sup>Parameter `-Include` is only valid when the path ends with `\*` OR if the `-Recurse` switch is used</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To get items from today, you could do something similar:

`Get-Childitem $folder * -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date }`

As for the multiple locations - I would suggest creating an array of folders you want to search and then iterating through the array.